# How to commit some instructions only

Tags: plsql, transactions

Let's say I have a sql script that deletes, updates and inserts...and at one time I have another update and I want to commit this update only. How can I do that ?

```
delete 1
delete 2
....
insert 1
....
update 1
....
insert 2
...
**update 2**
```

I would like to commit update 2 only... should I use a block or something ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: [Autonomous transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10713/transact.htm#CNCPT88959)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you intend exactly? Please provide the tablenames, insert/update scripts etc. Probably you should review what you actually need to do, because what you are trying to do seems to be absurd, and avoidable.

This is technically possible though:

You can put `update 2` inside a block(procedure) with `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`. That way if you commit inside that block, only  update 2 will be committed.
This is however, a bad and messy fix-  using `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` for anyting other than logging purpose is.You will most probably end up ruining with the data integrity and flow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PL/SQL directly? If you were using C/C++ and OCI you can use multiple transactions within a single db connection and switch between them. Something like that is not possible in PL/SQL. In PL/SQL you can use only AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTIONS.